# HTML SELECT - Change selected option by VALUE using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

There can be many options in a SELECT dropdown.

```
<select id="sel">
    <option value="car">1</option>
    <option value="bike">2</option>
    <option value="cycle">3</option>
    ...
</select>
```

I'm creating a *Update Profile* page where a user's profile is retrieved from the database and a form is shown with those values. When it comes to `SELECT`dropdown, there are many options. So, its tedious test all values

```
if (value == '1')
    echo "<option selected value='car'>1</option>";`
```

So, I want to have the corresponding option selected from its value. Like when I do something like `sel.value = 'bike'` using JavaScript the option **2** should be selected.

Comment: Are you sure `value="car"` and the text is `1`, and not the other way around?  Is the `<select>` code static, or dynamically created from something like a database?

Comment: You want to select this with the serverside? Why no serverside tag?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You can select the value using javascript:

```
document.getElementById('sel').value = 'bike';
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xkqTR/)

Comment: Remember: you may use sel.value = 'bike' instead of document.getElementById('sel').value

Comment: @EduardoXavier, if you first run 'var sel = document.getElementById('sel');', then yes, you can. Otherwise, no, you can't. If the element only has `id`, the only way is to get the element first. However, if it has the `name` attribute and it is inside a form, you can use `formelement.sel.value`. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element and http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-nameditem

Comment: @DenilsonSá This question is about the use of the "id". What you said about form and names is rigth but you're completly wrong when you say I can't access an element in the way I proposed. Let us do some practice then, have a look at here https://jsfiddle.net/tub6f0Lg/ :P
cheers!

Comment: @EduardoXavier: I stand corrected, you are right! Thanks for pointing it out! :) http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object However, although handy, relying on IDs being available as global variables because of window object may lead to messy and unreadable code. Consider another developer (maybe even yourself after a while) reading the code.

Comment: http://javascriptstutorial.com/blog/selecting-dropdown-element-using-javascript-or-jquery/

Answer (score 39):

If you are using jQuery:

```
$('#sel').val('bike');
```

Answer (score 13):

try out this....

[**JSFIDDEL DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xkqTR/257/)

using javascript

```
​document.getElementById('sel').value = 'car';​​​​​​​​​​
```

using jQuery

```
$('#sel').val('car');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('drpSelectSourceLibrary').value = 'Seven';
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).