# Select dropdown in Java script without using selectedindex

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use below javascript to select the month value.I need to get the dropdown selection without using index.As the month values are taken from other file.Please help me.
HTML:

```
<select name="param[start_month]">
<option label="Jan" value="1">Jan</option>
<option label="Feb" value="2">Feb</option>
<option label="Mar" value="3">Mar</option>
<option label="Apr" value="4">Apr</option>
<option label="May" value="5">May</option>
<option label="Jun" value="6">Jun</option>
<option label="Jul" value="7">Jul</option>
<option label="Aug" value="8">Aug</option>
<option label="Sep" value="9">Sep</option>
<option label="Oct" value="10">Oct</option>
<option label="Nov" value="11">Nov</option>
<option label="Dec" value="12" selected="selected">Dec</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementsByName("param[start_month]").value="Jan"
```

also i tried this too

```
document.getElementsByName("param[start_month]").label="Jan"
```

Comment: [How do I programmatically set the value of a select box element using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78932/); [HTML SELECT - Change selected option by VALUE using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265596/);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the option bu using [attribute equals selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) and set selected property.

```js
document.querySelector("[name='param[start_month]'] option[label='Jan']").selected = true;
```

```html
<select name="param[start_month]">
  <option label="Jan" value="1">Jan</option>
  <option label="Feb" value="2">Feb</option>
  <option label="Mar" value="3">Mar</option>
  <option label="Apr" value="4">Apr</option>
  <option label="May" value="5">May</option>
  <option label="Jun" value="6">Jun</option>
  <option label="Jul" value="7">Jul</option>
  <option label="Aug" value="8">Aug</option>
  <option label="Sep" value="9">Sep</option>
  <option label="Oct" value="10">Oct</option>
  <option label="Nov" value="11">Nov</option>
  <option label="Dec" value="12" selected="selected">Dec</option>
</select>
```

---

Or set the value as the value of the attribute specified. Although [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns collection of elements you need to get element by index.

```js
document.getElementsByName("param[start_month]")[0].value = "1"
```

```html
<select name="param[start_month]">
  <option label="Jan" value="1">Jan</option>
  <option label="Feb" value="2">Feb</option>
  <option label="Mar" value="3">Mar</option>
  <option label="Apr" value="4">Apr</option>
  <option label="May" value="5">May</option>
  <option label="Jun" value="6">Jun</option>
  <option label="Jul" value="7">Jul</option>
  <option label="Aug" value="8">Aug</option>
  <option label="Sep" value="9">Sep</option>
  <option label="Oct" value="10">Oct</option>
  <option label="Nov" value="11">Nov</option>
  <option label="Dec" value="12" selected="selected">Dec</option>
</select>
```